# How to swap file names that contain a hyphen (-) in a batch file? abc-def to def-abc

Tags: batch-file, filenames

I reverse video files in a batch using ffmpeg.

What I would like to do now is:

1. Reverse only the files with a "-" in the name.
2. Rename these files by swapping the part before "-" with the part after it. Like "abc-def" becomes "def-abc".

Any ideas?

Thanks!

UPDATE:

I tried the following now to find the files. For some reason it always succeeds, no matter which name:

```
for %%a in ("videos/*.mp4") do (
    echo %%a|find "-" >nul
    if %errorlevel%==0 (
        echo found
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your filenames do not include exclamation points, *(`!`)*, then something like this may work for you:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
For /F "Delims=" %%G In (
    '"(Set PATHEXT=) & "%SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe" /F "Videos":"*-*.mp4" 2> NUL"'
) Do Call :Sub %%G
GoTo :EOF

:Sub
Set "FN=%~n1"
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "RS="
Set "FS=%FN:-=" & Set "RS=-!FS!!RS!" & Set "FS=%"
EndLocal & Ren %1 "%FS%%RS%%~x1"
Exit /B
```

*Please note that no checks have been made for problematic resulting filenames, so if you had `Videos\foo - bar.mp4` the resulting rename would be `Videos\ bar-foo .mp4`, and filenames with leading or trailing spaces could cause you future issues.*

Comment: Not sure yet what you are doing here exactly but it works ;)
I guess in the first part you search all mp4s with a "-" and then you go to the second part for each one and rename them. Still have to combine that with my ffmpeg reverse but that shouldn't be too hard. Thanks!!